# Correlation between two groups over a set of treatments for a continuous value

Tags: correlation, continuous-data, group-differences, treatment-effect, spearman-rho

I have two groups tested with a set of treatments, and the measured quantity is continuous. Is there a good way to compute the correlation between the two groups?

For example, I have two types of plants $X$ and $Y$, and I make subgroups $A-G$ for each type, $X_A, X_B, ..., X_G,$ and $Y_A, Y_B, ..., Y_G$. $X_A$ and $Y_A$ are treated with nutrient $A$, $X_B$ and $Y_B$ are treated with $B$, etc. I measure the height of each plant after the treatment.

Now, I see that the growth seems to be $A<B<...<G$ for both $X$ and $Y$. What is the best way to express this in terms of correlation? Will Spearman's rho be acceptable?

EDIT:

My understanding is that Pearson's correlation is defined when there is a one-to-one correspondence between X and Y, like $(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (x_n, y_n)$.
In this case I can use $(\overline X_A, \overline Y_A), (\overline X_B, \overline Y_B), ...$ where $\overline X_A$ denotes the average of the heights in subgroup $X_A$. But there is not direct correspondence between the individual samples in $X_A$ and $Y_A$ (even the number of samples are not always exactly equal), and I am wondering if there is a better way than using the subgroup averages for computing correlation.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to contradict the first one. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Maybe the word "group" is confusing. There are  two high-level groups (X and Y, types of plants), then each one is separated into subgroups for treatment (A...G). The measured quantity is continuous (height of the plant) after treatment, and the effect of the treatments on the height seems to follow the same order for both X and Y (i.e., heights of X_A < heights of X_B < ...,  and heights of Y_A < heights of Y_B < ... etc. on the average.